# Instantiating a MonoGame in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, monogame, openal

I'm having basically the same problem as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555266/manually-instantiating-a-monogame-game) in which I obtain a NullReferenceException on attempting to instantiate a new MonoGame (after referencing the dlls from Visual Studio with OpenAL installed).  Is there a known resolution for this? Am I better off just creating my own game loop? How would I best go about doing that to maintain cross-platform compatibility?

Comment: Are we talking Xamarin iOS or Android? Or do you get the same error on both?

Comment: I've been trying to instantiate it in the main project, actually. I'm not sure if I'm referencing the correct dlls but the MonoGame class shows up so I assume they are.